Mail servers setup - HA
I want to setup mail service in my org in such a way that they are highly available and even if one of the server goes down the other will keep on serving the traffic.
The scenario is like below:
the internal apps will connect to the internal mail servers (in HA high availability), and then once the mails are received by internal mail mail servers they will further relay it to external mail servers (they are withing org, but internet facing, again HA), then those servers will be forwarding the mail according to receipient.
these servers mainly be for relaying the mails outwards and the from domain would be different to what these mail servers will be on. For example, the mail could be coming from helloworld.com, asdf.com and etc, however, the servers are hosted on testing.com.
So any tried and tested HA setup available for this, which someone already be using it for?
internal apps --> "internal servers" --> "external relay servers" --> outside
The mails will be like below:
from: john@asdffff.com
to: tom@foo.org
Their apps will just send the mails to us with relay settings. How can I setup this in HA?
The setup is being done on centos9 with postfix as mail server software.

This might be better asked in Server Fault, but check their help center first and make sure you're providing all the relevant information.

What's the actual question? Having two redundant servers is probably a step in the right direction, but it's not clear what sort of failure scenarios you are trying to mitigate against. A message which is on only one of the servers will be lost of that server crashes; Postfix is fairly resilient against this but there are obviously scenarios where the built-in mechanisms are insufficient (catastrophic disk failure, etc)

These servers are VM on vmware, so in terms of hardware failure we are covered, as they migrate to another host. However, if the server gets restarted or during patching we need to take one out the other server can keep the traffic running.
They will be accepting mails from internal network and then forwarding accordingly to internet. They will not host any mailboxes as that would add complexity in terms of shared storage.
Has anyone setup such scenario at their end? How you guys did it?

If you're just talking postfix (mail delivery/relay), then all you really need is something like haproxy to act as an smtp proxy/load balancer between the clients and servers, and can direct clients to an Available server if one is down.

Highly available mail storage is significantly more complicated, and often unnecessary. Most of what postfix stores is transient data like queued mail and lookup tables, so unless you have huge mail queues
If necessary, you would usually separate that into a different service that can handle filesystem/database replication and failover. Postfix doesn't make it very easy, but you could replace it with something like DBMail or dovecot for example, especially if you're hosting POP/IMAP mailboxes

For more information and solutions, take a look through the answers here: How to build a high availability Postfix system?
